# Can I create and maintain a tag to support unity-tweak-tool?

Tags: discussion, tags

Unity Tweak tool is a configuration tool meant for Ubuntu that I and some of my friends are working on. It is not yet available in official repositories but we provide a PPA for those who want to try and test it.

Recently, there was a [question about troubleshooting Unity tweak tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249401/application-unity-tweak-tool-is-not-starting-from-ubuntu-dash) asked on Ask Ubuntu. One of the team member stumbled upon the question and we are now working on solving the user's question.

Despite a number of our team members being relatively active on Ask Ubuntu, we only accidentally managed to find that question. We are optimistic that more questions would get asked on Ask Ubuntu and given the number of questions that get asked on Ask Ubuntu every day, catching them would get invariably difficult over time.

I believe it is a decent idea to create a tag to support our software product and I am hopeful it would help us better track and answer such questions in the future.

I am starting this question just so we can discuss any issues with having the aforementioned tag. If the community consensus is in support of having a tag, I'll ensure the questions with the tag meet community standards.

Comment: I actually thought about this myself...  We have one for ccsm, gnome tweak tool and ubuntu-tweak.  I don't see where UTT would be that different.

Comment: Surprised that you need to ask, Just Do It(tm).

Comment: while you're at it, don't forget to fill up the tag wiki and tag wiki exerpts from the getgo ;p

Comment: my first question in askubuntu was about this tool and got closed. :D

Comment: The tag exists but no one is subscribed to it (if I can read the info correctly).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I think such a tag should exist. A couple of considerations:

- If you want to keep apprised of Unity Tweak Tool questions, you should still search for Unity-Tweak-Tool (and variations) using the in-site search, Google (and/or other web search engines), and perhaps even the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. The presence of this tag doesn't guarantee it will always be used.
- You may want to clarify what it means to "ensure the questions with the tag meet community standards." In particular, if this tag exists it should *not* be *removed* from bad questions that are about Unity-Tweak-Tool. If a question is about Unity-Tweak-Tool doesn't meet community standards for a good question--say, it doesn't make sense, so it's NARQ, or it's really a call for discussion and debate, so it's NC--the [unity-tweak-tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/unity-tweak-tool) tag should remain on it (even as it is closed and eventually deleted).

Comment: Meeting community standards as in only allowing answerable questions on Ask Ubuntu and not feature requests and bug reports.

Comment: @jokerdino Ah, I understand. Yes, I agree that the Unity-Tweak-Tool team should not use Ask Ubuntu as a bug tracker or discussion forum, but *should* feel free to use AU as a question+answer site (within the scope of the FAQ), as you intend.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you're going to maintain it, **just do it**.

Answer (score 4):

I also think this is a good idea. It will be especially useful if the developers of the tool subscribed to the tag.

We already have tags for [ccsm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ccsm), [gnome-tweak-tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome-tweak-tool) and [gnome-tweak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome-tweak).  I don't see where a tag for [unity-tweak-tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/unity-tweak-tool) would be any different.